# How to handle JSON.stringify data in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to catch data from Ajax in Laravel controller to save it. But I keep getting error as seen image below. What am I doing wrong here?

Laravel Controller@ajaxstore

```
public function ajaxstore(Request $request)
{

    //Event::create($request->all());
    //return (gettype($name));
    $data = $request->all();
    //$newdata =array_keys($data);
    $data= json_decode($data,true);
    $event = New Event;        
    $event->name = $data['name'];
    $event->description = $data['description'];
    $event->start = $data['start'];
    $event->end = $data['end'];
    $event->color = $data['color'];
    $event->save();
}
```

My jquery

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: '/admin/event-list/' + roomId.val(),
    //events: JSON.parse(json_events),
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    timezone: 'local',
    select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
        endtime = end.format('LLLL');
        starttime = start.format('LLLL');
        room_id = roomId.val();
        var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
        startTime.val(start);
        endTime.val(end);
        $('#dayClick #when').text(mywhen);
        $("#dayClick").modal("show");
        $('#submitButton').on('click', function(event){
            console.log("clicked");
            if(createEvent.valid()){
                // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
                if(doSubmit(start, end))
                {

                    $("#dayClick").modal('hide');
                    // remove previous entry
                    $("#createEvent").each(function(){
                        this.reset();
                    });
                    console.log($('#apptStartTime').val());
                    console.log($('#apptEndTime').val());
                    // enter to the calender
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: $('#createEvent #event-name').val(),
                            start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
                            end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
                        },
                        true);
                    console.log("after renderEvent");

                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("failed");
                };
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        //return eventData;
    },
    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#modalTitle').html(event.name);
        $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
        $('#eventUrl').attr({'href':'event/'+event.id,'target':'_self'});
        $('#fullCalModal').modal("show");
    }
});

function doSubmit(start, end){
    console.log("inside dosubmit");
    eventData.name = eventName.val();
    eventData.description = description.val();
    eventData.capacity = capacity.val();
    eventData.room_id = roomId.val();
    startDate =  moment(start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
    eventData.start = startDate;
    endDate =  moment(end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
    eventData.end = endDate;
    eventData.color = color.val();
    console.log("inputdata: " + JSON.stringify(eventData));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'/admin/event-ajaxstore',
        //url: '/admin/event-ajaxstore',
        data: JSON.stringify(eventData),
        success: function(response){
            //event.id = response.eventid;
            console.log("returned : " + typeof(response));
            /* $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event); */ 
            /* //json_events = response; */
            /* console.log("data: " + data); */
            return true;
        }
    });


}
```

[image]

When I run this in the contoller;

```
    $data = $request->all();
    return (json_decode($data));
```

I get the following error.

> local.ERROR: ErrorException: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be
>   string, array given in
>   /Users/sokada/Code/backpack-aktiv/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/EventController.php:39

Comment: I spent hours trying to get Laravel JSON POST testing, and my controller, and a front-end that used stringify. I eventually gave up and changed the front-end to not send stringify and all my problems were solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that [$request->all()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_all) already returns an array. So you dont need the `json_decode()`

```
$data = $request->all();
$data= json_decode($data,true);  // remove this, you don't need it here
```

**Do keep in mind though that `$request->all()` is going to return ALL variables. which may or may not be what you expect**

If it were me, I would send my data like this:

`data: JSON.stringify({eventData:eventData}),`

Then I would access it in my controller like this:

`$data = $request->input('eventData');`

Comment: This gives an error, "Call to a member function input() on array".

Comment: @shin can you show the full new code? `$request` shown in your code above is definitely a `std class` object and not an array, seems somehow in your new code, you have cast `$request` to an array or overwritten the variable

Comment: Are you sure you didnt mistakenly type `$request->all()->input()`, that would cause that error